# AngularJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to wrap my mind around what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to pull json data from a php file and then display it in my Angular app.

**My app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("ClientHealthCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('json.php').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.rows = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // log error
    });
});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<body class="skin-black" ng-app="MyApp">
...
<tbody ng-controller="ClientHealthCtrl">
  <tr class="link_back" ng-repeat="Computer in rows">
    <td><a href="#cid={{Computer.id}}">{{Computer.ComputerName}}</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-square" style="color:#008000;"></i>{{Computer.WmiTest}}</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-square" style="color:#008000;"></i>{{Computer.SmsClientService}}</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-square" style="color:#008000;"></i>{{Computer.McAfeeFrameworkService}}</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-square" style="color:#008000;"></i>{{Computer.RemoteManagement}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Which results in...**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:2067:13
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:113:18)
    at forEach.after (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:2066:5)
    at Object.JQLite.(anonymous function) [as after] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:2104:17)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:13294:22
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:3745:29
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:13293:13)
    at Object.Scope.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:7693:38)
    at Object.Scope.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:7894:24)
    at done (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:8883:20) 
    enter code here
```

Comment: Are you certain the data schema is as you expect it to be? Have you logged out the value of 'data' in your success handler?

Comment: Adding console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.rows)); to the success handler displays the json content correctly in the console. So if nothing else I know that $scope.rows is not null.

Comment: I had the same error but found it to be caused by a ng-include directive, so make sure you check that in your code.

Answer (score 7):

Try wrapping the `<tr>...</tr>` element inside a `<div>...</div>`.

Looking at the source code of Angular, it is complaining some node has no parent node.

Actually, I found out your question when looking to fix the same error in my code.
It's what I did, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Rave, I had a div for ng-include inside ui-view div, and was getting same error, as per your suggestion added wrapper div for ng-include div and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace suggests that something is going wrong when it's trying to execute a for-loop ("at forEach", "at forEach.after"), and since it's from a JQLite function I would say it's an Angular based loop.

Looking at the code you have provided, I would take a guess that the loop in question is the ng-repeat in your view. Which almost certainly means your "Computer" object is null.

badsyntax is spot on with his comment. I would add some console.logs into the success handler to see what "data" is. Your logging also seems a bit lite in the error handler. Are you confident the http call is completing succesfully?

Comment: Adding console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.rows)); to the success handler displays the json content correctly in the console. So if nothing else I know that $scope.rows is not null.

Comment: does $scope.rows contain the actual data? Or is it wrapped in another "data" property?

Comment: Pretty sure it contains the actual data. Not wrapping it in anything.